# Android: Styling the Tab Bar for multiple versions

Tags: android, android-theme, android-tabs

I'm trying to use xml to style my tabs. I'm following this guide: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html

My app spans versions 2.3.3 to 4.3. I'd put up my code, but honestly I don't have any because I don't know where to start. The tutorial doesn't seem to work at all for me. All I'm looking to do is change the background color of the tabs and the text color. Eclipse generated a structure that has styles.xml files in folders `values`, `values-v11`, and `values-v14`. Here is my base styles.xml. I'm honestly just not sure what tags go where in which files.

## Update

I've imported the v4 and v7 support libraries. Also, now my styles.xml looks like this

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="TCMBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="TCMTheme" parent="TCMBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/TCMActionBarTabs</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar tabs styles -->
<style name="TCMActionBarTabs"
       parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:background">@color/tcmblue</item>
    <!-- tab indicator -->


    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="background">@color/tcmblue</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

I've set `TCMBaseTheme` as my theme in my manifest. There are now no errors, however when I run the app there's no change to the tabbar color.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing:

```
<item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/TCMActionBarTabs</item>
```

in the TCMTheme `style`.